# method(E[]) is not applicable to the arguments(int[])

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I'm trying to implement my sort method, which takes a generic `E[]` as an argument, upon my `int[]`. I receive the error:

> The method sort(E[]) in the type HeapSort is not applicable for the arguments (int[]).

My code is as follows:

```
public <E extends Comparable<E>> void sort(E[] array){

//my code

}
```

---

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] arr = new int[30];
    for(int rep = 0; rep < arr.length; rep++){
        arr[rep] =(int )(Math.random() * 100 + 0);
    }

    System.out.println("The unsorted Array: ");
    System.out.println(sort(arr).toString());
}
```

Any ideas as to why I get this error? All help appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: `System.out.println(sort(arr).toString());` is invalid because this `sort()` method returns `void`.

Comment: The error message is clear enough. What do you not understand about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A primitive type can't replace a generic type parameter (and even if it could, it couldn't satisfy your `extends Comparable<E>` type bound, since primitive types don't extend any class and don't implement any interface).

You can replace your `int[]` with an `Integer[]` and it will work.

Beside that error, `sort(arr)` doesn't return anything, so you can't execute `toString` on it.

You can replace it with :

```
new HeapSort ().sort(arr); // you must create an instance of the class that contains
                           // the sort method in order to call it
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Comment: Thank you all very much. I'm feeling sort of dumb now because that seems to be a given. However, I now receive the error: "- Cannot invoke sort() on the array type Integer[]". Thank you for your help

Comment: @A.Takami Is your sort method supposed to be static? Your code attempts to call it from a static context (the main method) without creating an instance of the class that contains `sort`.

Comment: My sort method is not static. Yeah I was just trying to call my `sort` in any type of way. when I posted this and didn't really think twice. How might be the proper way to call my non-static sort from a the main?

Comment: @A.Takami `new HeapSort ().sort(arr);`

Comment: I can't thank you enough. I'm a student and really just trying to learn.

Answer (score 1):

lets look at what you wrote there.

```
public <E extends Comparable<E>> void sort(E[] array)
```

this is a method called sort. it has generic parameter with a constraint. The constraint is that whatever the generic parameter you have put in, it must implement Comparable.

`int` doesn't implement `Comparable`, in fact `int` doesn't implement anything.

Java generics don't work with primitive types at all. Generic constraints only limit you farther.